# Joi validation return only one error message

Tags: validation, hapi.js

I have a three field form made of a name field, email field and a textarea. I'm using Joi 4.7.0 version along with hapijs. I use the object below validate the input. I receive the data object from an ajax call. When I fill all the three fields with wrong informations I get only the message relative to the first wrong field. Like that:

```
"{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"name is not allowed to be empty","validation":    {"source":"payload","keys":["data.name"]}}"
```

---

```
validate: {
      payload: {
        data: {
          name: Joi.string().min(3).max(20).required(),
          email: Joi.string().email().required(),
          message: Joi.string().min(3).max(1000).required()
        }
      }
}
```

For explanation let suppose to not fill the three field. I get only one message error and not the message error of the others fields. Why?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It happens because Joi aborts early by default.

> `abortEarly` - when `true`, stops validation on the first error, otherwise returns all the errors found. Defaults to `true`.

***EDIT:** Configuration has changed in hapi 8.0. You need to add `abortEarly: false` to the `routes` config:

```
var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8000,
    routes: {
        validate: {
            options: {
                abortEarly: false
            }
        }
    }
});
```

*See the [Joi API documentation](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v9.0.4/API.md#validatevalue-schema-options-callback) for more details.
*Also, see `validation` under [Hapi Route options](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md#route-options).

So Joi stops the validation on the first error:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var Joi = require('joi');

var server = new Hapi.Server('localhost', 8000);

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{first}/{second}',
    config: {
        validate: {
            params: {
                first: Joi.string().max(5),
                second: Joi.string().max(5)
            }
        }
    },
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        reply('example');
    }
});

server.start();

server.inject('/invalid/invalid', function (res) {

    console.log(res.result);
});
```

Outputs:

```
{ statusCode: 400,
  error: 'Bad Request',
  message: 'first length must be less than or equal to 5 characters long',
  validation: { source: 'params', keys: [ 'first' ] } }
```

You can however configure Hapi to return all errors. For this, you need to set `abortEarly` to `false`. You can do this in server configuration:

```
var server = new Hapi.Server('localhost', 8000, { validation: { abortEarly: false } });
```

If you run the script now, you get:

```
{ statusCode: 400,
  error: 'Bad Request',
  message: 'first length must be less than or equal to 5 characters long. second length must be less than or equal to 5 characters long',
  validation: { source: 'params', keys: [ 'first', 'second' ] } }
```

Answer (score 42):

I'm not integrating with hapi.js, but I noticed that there is a `ValidationOptions` object which can be passed along. Inside that object is an `abortEarly` option, so this should work:

`Joi.validate(request, schema, { abortEarly: false }`

This can also be configured as follows:

```
Joi.object().options({ abortEarly: false }).keys({...});
```

Check out these type definitions for more `ValidationOptions`:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/blob/master/typings/joi/joi.d.ts

Comment: it still works in 2020 with node v12.18.0 and hapi 17.1.1, thanks saved me a lot of time 

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 5):

The `validation` key no longer works with the `Hapi.Server` constructor in Hapi 8.0:

> [1] validation is not allowed

I found the solution in a [GitHub issue for hapi](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/2279#issuecomment-66786470):

```js
var Hapi = require('hapi');


var server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({
  host: HOST,
  port: PORT,
  routes: {
    validate: {
      options: {
        abortEarly: false
      }
    }
  }
});

// Route using Joi goes here.
server.route({});

server.start(function () {
  console.log('Listening on %s', server.info.uri);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

After some research, I found out it can be solved 2 ways:

```
[Segments.BODY]: Joi.object().keys({
value: Joi.string().required().error(new Error('Value is required and has to be a text!')),
})
```

or

```
[Segments.BODY]: Joi.object().keys({
password: Joi.string().required().pattern(new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}$')).min(8).label('Password').messages({
    'string.pattern.base': 'Your {#label} does not matche the suggested pattern',
    'string.base': `Your {#label} should match the suggested pattern`,
    'string.empty': `Your {#label} can not be empty`,
    'string.min': `Your {#label} has to be at least {#limit} chars`,
    'any.required': `Your {#label} is required`,
}),
})
```